# for each unique value in a column extract lines and save separately

Tags: awk, sed

Is there a way to separately extract lines with similar values and save them separately?
my file is as follows

```
319 Eukaryota;Alveolata;Apicomplexa;Aconoidasida;Piroplasmorida;Babesia;Babesia;Babesia_canis_canis;AY072926.1.1714;    88e823b2-69c5-4be5-9338-f5ce58c41ae0
443 Eukaryota;Alveolata;Apicomplexa;Aconoidasida;Piroplasmorida;Babesia;Babesia;Babesia_conradae;AF158702.1.1717;   01a792e5-de00-43bb-9918-8d692a7b3226
355 Eukaryota;Alveolata;Apicomplexa;Aconoidasida;Piroplasmorida;Babesia;Babesia;Babesia_duncani;HQ285838.1.1768;    1a9762a7-b4aa-4824-a416-5986d62a43e2
313 Eukaryota;Alveolata;Apicomplexa;Aconoidasida;Piroplasmorida;Babesia;Babesia;Babesia_duncani;HQ285838.1.1768;    1c89bfe3-3cff-4c29-b8c9-1bc2801106b7
464 Eukaryota;Alveolata;Apicomplexa;Aconoidasida;Piroplasmorida;Babesia;Babesia;Babesia_duncani;HQ285838.1.1768;    2a16a0ca-7395-4c82-8c76-13ee3121a177
419 Eukaryota;Alveolata;Apicomplexa;Aconoidasida;Piroplasmorida;Babesia;Babesia;Babesia_duncani;HQ285838.1.1768;    459673b9-73a8-4044-9c0e-df30fae71ac7
321 Eukaryota;Alveolata;Apicomplexa;Aconoidasida;Piroplasmorida;Theileria;Theileria;Theileria_annulata;AY508467.1.1741; 4c8b0eb7-31fe-4001-bdf2-9c75b55cce13
307 Eukaryota;Alveolata;Apicomplexa;Aconoidasida;Piroplasmorida;Theileria;Theileria;Theileria_annulata;DQ287944.1.1732; 0bbaa64e-9b4d-4891-88df-dadaacbfa10c
481 Eukaryota;Alveolata;Apicomplexa;Aconoidasida;Piroplasmorida;Theileria;Theileria;Theileria_annulata;KT367879.1.1727; 0f12631e-1004-4b59-af15-11f9fa387efa
```

My desired result is to extract the third column of all lines for each unique 2nd column:

file1 for Babesia_canis_canis;

```
88e823b2-69c5-4be5-9338-f5ce58c41ae0
```

file2 for Babesia_conradae;

```
01a792e5-de00-43bb-9918-8d692a7b3226
```

file3 for Babesia_duncani;

```
1a9762a7-b4aa-4824-a416-5986d62a43e2
1c89bfe3-3cff-4c29-b8c9-1bc2801106b7
2a16a0ca-7395-4c82-8c76-13ee3121a177
459673b9-73a8-4044-9c0e-df30fae71ac7
```

file4 for Theileria_annulata;

```
4c8b0eb7-31fe-4001-bdf2-9c75b55cce13
0bbaa64e-9b4d-4891-88df-dadaacbfa10c
0f12631e-1004-4b59-af15-11f9fa387efa
```

I tried awk but i could not separate the files:

```
awk '{c[$2]++; a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2]RS$0:$0}
END{for(k in a) if(c[k]>1) print a[k]}' file
```

Comment: How do you count the columns? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk -F'[; ]*' '{fn=$(NF-2);print $NF >> fn; close(fn)}' input_file
```

Note that I'm closing the file descriptor explicitly after every use. I'm doing this to avoid running into too many open file descriptors in case there are many different output files. If the input_file is ordered by the output filename, like in your example, this is superfluous, but it doesn't hurt either unless this gets performance critical. If that's the case, consider to remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach seems valid, but not quite complete. You need to index the array in `awk` based on the unique identifier names. e.g. `Babesia_canis_canis`. Splitting the second column on `;` delimiter and extracting the value at `n-2`th index of `arr` would have the unique key.

```
awk '{
    n = split($2, arr, ";")
    key = arr[n - 2]
    unique[key] = unique[key] ? unique[key] RS $NF : $NF
}

END {
    for (id in unique) {
        print unique[id] > id
    }
    close(id)
}' file
```

should work on any `awk` as no GNU specific constructs are used. This is efficient in terms of disk I/O by causing fewer number of writes, but stores content from each line in memory.

Comment: I see that you are just fixing what the OP provided in the question. But note that this approach would consume a bunch of memory (more or less the input file's size)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/.*;\(.*\);.*;\s*\(\S\+\).*/echo "\2" >> "\1".txt/e' file
```

Append the second column of data from each line to a file indicated by being a string in the first column between the second from last and last `;`.